# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:377 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview

Filter on `RecyclerView` crashes and gives an error.
Its work most of the time but some time crashes and gives this error:
`Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 1(offset:1).state:377 androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`

```kotlin
class HomeFragmentCoursesAdapter(
    var context: Context,
    private val mItemClickListener: CourseClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeFragmentCoursesAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {

    var selectedCourseArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    private var usersList = ArrayList<CourseListApiModel.Data>()
    private var filterList = ArrayList<CourseListApiModel.Data>()

    init {
        filterList = usersList
    }

    interface CourseClickListener {
        fun courseItemClick(selectedCourse: ArrayList<String>)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.home_bottom_sheet_recycler_view_item_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = filterList[position]
        holder.courseName.text = user.courseName
        holder.checkBox.tag = position
        holder.checkBox.isChecked = selectedCourseArray.contains(user.id.toString())

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener {
            val taggedPosition = it.tag as Int
            val course = filterList[taggedPosition]
            if (selectedCourseArray.contains(course.id.toString())) {
                selectedCourseArray.remove(course.id.toString())
            } else {
                selectedCourseArray.add(course.id.toString())
                mItemClickListener.courseItemClick(selectedCourseArray)
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return filterList.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var courseName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.university_text)
        var checkBox: CheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox)
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

                val charSearch = constraint.toString()
                filterList =
                    if (charSearch.isEmpty()) {
                        usersList
                    } else {
                        val resultList = ArrayList<CourseListApiModel.Data>()
                        for (row in filterList) {
                            if (
                                row.courseName
                                    .lowercase(Locale.ROOT)
                                    .contains(charSearch.lowercase(Locale.ROOT))
                            ) {
                                resultList.add(row)
                            }
                        }
                        resultList
                    }

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = filterList
                return filterResults
            }

            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
                filterList = results?.values as ArrayList<CourseListApiModel.Data>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun updateData(newList: ArrayList<CourseListApiModel.Data>) {
        usersList.clear()
        usersList.addAll(newList)
        filterList = usersList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun clearFilter() {
        filterList.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun addDataInFilter() {
        filterList = usersList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```